# Como usar en un mismo layout CardView + ListView?

Tags: android, material-design-lite

Estoy interesado en crear un layout dividido en dos partes, en la parte superior una `CardView` (Creo que no tengo que usar `RecyclerView`, ya que solo necesito una) os dejo esta imagen como ejemplo:

[image: PARALLAX]

El problema que tengo es que la `CardView` solapa la `ListView` que me gustaria añadir debajo, ocupando la mitad inferior de la pantalla. Es correcta la implementacion de estas dos clases para el uso que le quiero dar? Os dejo mi layout a continuacion:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
        card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/foto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="24dp">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/nombre"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                        android:text="texto2"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/descripcion"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="texto3">

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listViewId"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:stackFromBottom="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Muchas gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a tu `Layout`, el `CardView` contendría los `TextView` y  quedaría :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
            card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/foto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="24dp">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/nombre"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                        android:text="texto2"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/descripcion"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="texto3" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listViewId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:stackFromBottom="false" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Este es un ejemplo de como se mostraría:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias pero no funciona!

Comment: He editado mi respuesta y agregué una imagen.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfectamente! Acabo de saber lo que queria hacer realmente y era utilizar "CoordinatorLayout" para crear el efecto PARALLAX! Aqui dejo un poco de informacion encontrada, espero que sirva de ayuda: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

Comment: Ah ok querías un parallax, puedes crearlo con  CoordinatorLayout, revisando tu link me parece que eso lo tomaron de: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare